# perform nested query in Python Graphene with distinct types in schema

Tags: graphql, graphene-python

I have the following data structure coming from a database:

```
[
   {
    'time': '2019-07-19T12:57:17Z', 
    'bizLocation': 'urn:epc:id:sgln:bizLocation.Company.3',
    'city': 'dallas',
    'countryCode': 'US',
    'humid': 49, 
    'sID': '40:61:32:22:11:00',
    'site': 'factory',
    'stype': 'BME280',
    'temp': 22.941
   }
]
```

I wish to create a GraphQL API to query the Database and provide the query in the following output:

```
[
{
   sID: String (same as sID),
   sType: String (same as sType),
   bizLocation: String (same as bizLocation),
   values: [
       {
         timestamp: Datetime (same as time),
         value: Float (value of 'temp')
         mType: 'temp'
       },
       {
         timestamp: Datetime (same as time),
         value: Float (value of 'humid'),
         mType: 'humid'
       }
   ]
}
]
```

I am using `Graphene` to just test if it might work. Currently I am just playing around with the idea and tried to make the following GraphQL Schema:

```
type SensorDoc {
   sID: String
   sType: String
   bizLocation: String
   values: [SensorData]
}

type SensorData {
   timestamp: String
   value: Float
   mType: String
}
```

Translated to Graphene is as follows:

```
import graphene

class SensorData(graphene.ObjectType):
    timestamp = graphene.DateTime()
    value = graphene.Float()
    mType = graphene.String()

class SensorDoc(graphene.ObjectType):
    sId = graphene.String()
    sType = graphene.String()
    bizLocation = graphene.String()
    values = graphene.List(SensorData)

class Query(graphene.ObjectType):

    sensor_data = graphene.List(SensorDoc)
    def resolve_sensor_data(self, info):
        # DB Query Logic Here!!

        output = [] # output to return

        for each_point in list_result:
            SensorDoc(sId=each_point['sID'], sType=each_point['stype'], 
                bizLocation=each_point['bizLocation'],
                SensorData(timestamp=each_point['time'], 
    value=each_point['humid'], mType='humid') # <---- This is a SyntaxError
            )

            output.append(SensorDoc)
        return output
```

This wouldn't work since `SensorData` won't pass as keyword argument.

I am completely new to trying out Graphene and was wondering how is this achievable when the query should look like the following:

```
query{
   sensorData {
       sID
       sType
       bizLocation
       values {
          timestamp
          value
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue by resolving the `values` within the `SensorDoc` class as follows:

```
class SensorData(graphene.ObjectType):
    timestamp = graphene.String()
    temp = graphene.Float()
    humid = graphene.Float()


class SensorDoc(graphene.ObjectType):
    sId = graphene.String()
    sType = graphene.String()
    bizLocation = graphene.String()
    values = graphene.List(SensorData)

    def resolve_values(parent, info):
        # DB Query Logic
        output = [] # output to return

        for each_point in list_result:
            output.append(
               SensorData(timestamp=each_point['time'], temp=each_point['temp'], humid=each_point['humid'])
            )
        return output
```

And Within the main `Query` Class, kept the `resolve_sensor_doc` resolver:

```
class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
    sensor_doc = graphene.List(SensorDoc)

    def resolve_sensor_doc(self, info):
        # DB Query Logic

        output = []
        for each_point in list_result:
            output.append(
                SensorDoc(
                    sId=each_point['sID'], 
                    sType=each_point['stype'], 
                    bizLocation=each_point['bizLocation']
                )
            )
        return output
```

Finally the execution:

```
schema = graphene.Schema(query=Query)

result = schema.execute(
    '''
    query {
        sensorDoc{
            sId
            sType
            bizLocation
            values {
                timestamp
                temp
                humid
            }
        }
    }
    '''
)

items = dict(result.data.items())
print(json.dumps(items, indent=4))
```

Provides me the the output as follows:

```
{
    "sensorDoc": [
        {
            "sId": "60:64:05:9C:DF:F2",
            "sType": "BME280",
            "bizLocation": "urn:epc:id:sgln:bizLocation.3",
            "values": [
                {
                    "timestamp": "2019-07-19T12:57:17Z",
                    "temp": 22.941,
                    "humid": 49.0
                },
                {
                    "timestamp": "2019-07-19T12:57:19Z",
                    "temp": 22.981,
                    "humid": 47.0
                },
                {
                    "timestamp": "2019-07-19T12:57:21Z",
                    "temp": 23.001,
                    "humid": 47.0
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "sId": "60:64:05:9C:DF:F2",
            "sType": "BME280",
            "bizLocation": "urn:epc:id:sgln:bizLocation.3",
            "values": [
                {
                    "timestamp": "2019-07-19T12:57:17Z",
                    "temp": 22.941,
                    "humid": 49.0
                },
                {
                    "timestamp": "2019-07-19T12:57:19Z",
                    "temp": 22.981,
                    "humid": 47.0
                },
                {
                    "timestamp": "2019-07-19T12:57:21Z",
                    "temp": 23.001,
                    "humid": 47.0
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "sId": "60:64:05:9C:DF:F2",
            "sType": "BME280",
            "bizLocation": "urn:epc:id:sgln:bizLocation.3",
            "values": [
                {
                    "timestamp": "2019-07-19T12:57:17Z",
                    "temp": 22.941,
                    "humid": 49.0
                },
                {
                    "timestamp": "2019-07-19T12:57:19Z",
                    "temp": 22.981,
                    "humid": 47.0
                },
                {
                    "timestamp": "2019-07-19T12:57:21Z",
                    "temp": 23.001,
                    "humid": 47.0
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```